# Using text and json with postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

What is the best way to store json in a text field and have it queryable, while still being able to store 'just text'.

Example that doesn't work but I wish it did

```
create table test_json (id serial, data text);

insert into test_json (data) values ('some text that is not json')
insert into test_json (data) values ('{ "package_name" : "com.example" }')
```

If i wanted to pull out the package name of all records in the table, I thought I would do something like this:

```
select id, data::json->>"package_name" as package_name from test_json
```

This works fine if all the records are valid json, but what if some are not?  Is there anyway to just ...skip over them (pretend they're null or something)?

Thanks

Comment: You should convert your non-json data to json: `create table test_json (id serial, data json); insert into test_json (data) values (to_json('some text that is not json'))`.

Comment: So what you really want is to treat input as json if it's valid json, and otherwise skip/ignore it?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, that's what I'm looking to do

Comment: @Tometzky using a json field would probably be the 'correct 'way, but I've only encountered problems with it.  ``Cannot extract element from a scalar`` comes to mind.  That probably deserves a different question though.

Comment: @KyleGobel Then maybe you can use `insert into test_json(data_json) select row_to_json(t) from (values('some text that is not json')) t(_);`. This would allow you to use `data::json->>"package_name"` and return NULL for formerly text fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this (i hope your `some text that is not json` *doesn't contains* `{` )

```
select t.id,t.data->>'package_name' as package_name
from ( 
     select id,data::json from test_json where data ilike '%{%'
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (based on [answer from dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27745)):

```
create temporary table test_json (id serial, data json);
insert into test_json(data)
  select row_to_json(t) from (values('some text that is not json')) t(_);
```

Which would insert the following json data to `data`:

```
{"_":"some text that is not json"}
```

This would allow you to use `data->>'package_name'`, which would return NULL for formerly text fields, or use `data->>'_'` to extract text fields data.